# How to update on the DOM the value of a div in another function after fetch

Tags: javascript

I have a function that loads user information including followers and following,

From that function, I go to the 2nd function that loads a button

on clicking the button it goes to the 3rd function that changes the value in the backend.

After updating the value, how can I change the innerHTML of the divs in my first function that loads the user info?

The goal is to show the new value without refreshing the page.

The function that loads the user info.

```
function load_user_info(user_clicked_on){
    document.querySelector('#page-view').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('#posts-view').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('#show-posts').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('#load-profile').style.display = 'block';
    fetch(`/profile/${user_clicked_on}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(profile => {
            const profile_element = document.createElement('div');
            const followers = document.createElement('div');
            const following = document.createElement('div');
            followers.innerHTML = 'Followers: ' + profile.followers;
            following.innerHTML = 'Following: ' + profile.following;
            profile_element.appendChild(followers);
            profile_element.appendChild(following);
            profile_element.classList.add('profile_element');
            insert_follow_btn(user_clicked_on) // insert follow or unfollow button.
            document.querySelector('#user-profile').appendChild(profile_element);
        });
    document.querySelector('#user-profile').innerHTML = `<h3>${user_clicked_on.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + user_clicked_on.slice(1)} Profile</h3>`;
}
```

the function that inserts a button and then when clicking on the button it goes to the 3rd function that updates the value in the backend.

```
function insert_follow_btn(user_clicked_on){
    // For any other user who is signed in show the follow button
    current_logged_in_user = document.querySelector('#user_detail').value;
    if(user_clicked_on != current_logged_in_user){
        const profile_buttons = document.createElement('div');
        const follow_button = document.createElement('button');
        fetch(`/following/${user_clicked_on}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            result = data.result
            if(result == true){
              follow_button.innerHTML += 'UnFollow'
              profile_buttons.appendChild(follow_button);
              follow_button.addEventListener("click", () => {
                if(follow_button.innerHTML === 'Follow'){
                    follow_button.innerHTML = 'UnFollow'
                }else{
                    follow_button.innerHTML = 'Follow'
                }
                   unfollow_user(user_clicked_on)
                });
          }else{
              follow_button.innerHTML += 'Follow'
              profile_buttons.appendChild(follow_button);
              follow_button.addEventListener("click", () => {
                if(follow_button.innerHTML === 'Follow'){
                    follow_button.innerHTML = 'UnFollow'
                }else{
                    follow_button.innerHTML = 'Follow'
                }
                    follow_user(user_clicked_on)
                });
            }
        })
        profile_buttons.classList.add('profile_buttons');
        document.querySelector('#user-profile').appendChild(profile_buttons);
        console.log('Current profile:'+user_clicked_on+' Current logged in user: '+ current_logged_in_user);
    }else{
        return ``;
    }
}
```

the function that updates on the backend

```
function follow_user(user_clicked_on){
    fetch(`/follow/${user_clicked_on}`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            user_clicked_on: user_clicked_on
        })
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => {
            // Print result
          console.log(result.followers)
          // How to update my followers.innerHTML in load_user_info function?
        })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the followers div inside load_user_info give it an id, like "followersdiv":

```
const followers = document.createElement('div');
followers.setAttribute("id", "followersdiv");
```

Then, inside the last function, follow_user, you can:

```
console.log(result.followers);
document.querySelector('#followersdiv').innerHTML='Followers: ' + result.followers;
```

Or

```
document.getElementById('followersdiv').innerHTML='Followers: ' + result.followers;
```